# WakerBehaviour gets blocked by other activities

Tags: java, agents-jade, multi-agent

I am working on a multi-agent system in JADE and use WakerBehaviours to simulate events.
However, in some cases, the WakerBehaviour wakes up much too late which leads to problems. I have tested this in the following code, but the "Im awake"-message always pops up, AFTER the while-loop is completed. how could i avoid this?

```
public class Test_Agent extends Agent {
protected void setup() {
    Tools.prnt(this, "starting waker");
    addBehaviour(new TickerBehaviour(this, 1000) {
        protected void onTick() {
            Tools.prnt(myAgent, "Im awake.");
        }
    });
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 100000) {
        System.out.println(i+" waiting.");
        i++;
    }   
}
```

Thanks in advance!
Cheers, Jacek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, processing of behaviours starts after setup().
that is why you should move loops inside a behaviour and If you want to handle events during loop, avoid loops and use cycle behaviour (because behaviours is processed in turn).